# Tapping a link in hovered area is immediately activated on touch

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design, touch

I am currently building a responsive website and am having issues with a box that shows content and a button link on hover. On touch devices, if you tap the box in its hidden state exactly where the link is it immediately activates the link without giving a chance for the user to read the new content. If you tap anywhere around the link within the box then the hover state is applied as intended.

I'm pretty sure that the click event is triggered **after** the hover/mouseover event starting with touch, like `touchstart -> mouseover -> click`.

I tried doing some research around this and there doesn't seem to be much on this topic. Is there a good way to prevent the click from being triggered on the area for a single touch?

https://jsfiddle.net/bvcv018m/4/embedded/result/. Using Chrome's device emulator for the fiddle actually replicates this.

Example HTML

```
<div class="box">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250" alt="">
    <div class="hidden"> <!-- This is shown on hover -->
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis reiciendis. Try tapping the following button even in the hidden state. </p>
        <a href="#" class="button">Click This</a> <!-- Tapping this area activates the link immediately -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried several variations of listening to the `touchstart mouseover click` events but can't get anything solid that works across mobile/tablet and desktop.

Comment: Touch devices doesn't really have a over state, it's a bad practice to have an hover on touch device. You should rework the UX on mobile.

Comment: Makes me wonder why `mouseover` is even available on mobile. What if it is intentionally part of the mobile UX - like a 'Tap to Show' overlay? eg. https://jsfiddle.net/bvcv018m/5/embedded/result/

Comment: It is there because some site are not optimized for mobile device and would be un-navigable for touch screen without the hover states. *"Tap to show overlay"* is good. Basically, on touch, you check if the overlay is visible. If not, show it, else go to the link. Also, if you touch anywhere else on the screen that is not the element, hide the overlay.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. The logic is solid and is something I've tried, but as far as the button link is concerned, the hidden overlay will always be visible because `click` is registered after `mouseover` and `touchstart`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to figure out a workaround by setting `position: relative;` to the button and playing with the `z-index` value.

Essentially, the button's initial z order is -1 making it unclickable. When the overlay is tapped to show, the z order is brought up. The only extra bit was that the z index needed to be brought up after a slight delay since most mobile browsers have a (I think) 300ms delay between `touchstart -> touchend -> mouseover` and `click`. The delay was implemented with a `setTimeout` but I believe it can be done purely through CSS with a `transition-delay` on the `z-index`.

Answer (score 0):

Completely untested but mobile browsers use multiple click events that differ from desktop browsers.  This could work

```
$('#yourLinkID').one('touchstart', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Also though, my personal preference is not not have any "hover" effects on a mobile optimized site.  Especially if they have a click listener as well.  It simply doesn't work on most browsers